# Handling links from other apps: how does stackexchange android app do it?

Tags: android

If you're an avid user of stackexchange android app, you might have noticed this: make a Google search with chrome, if the SERP contains any link from any stackexchange site and you click it, it will automatically open stackexchange app and the clicked question will be loaded.

See an example :
[image]

Please, how can I achieve something similar with my app?

Comment: Its probably the website that detects a mobile device visiting the webpage and sends a response telling chrome to issue out a pending intent to any other apps on your phone that can handle the loading of the page. The stackexchange app probably makes use of a BroadcastReceiver. Just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should see Deep-linking chapter

https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Define intent filter for the activity (which is going to handle the url ) you want to launch in Manifest

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.android.LinkHandlerActivity"
android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
    <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
    <data android:scheme="example"
          android:host="gizmos" />

</intent-filter>
```

And then handle link in activity like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
Uri data = intent.getData();
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It is called Deep App Linking. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) is the tutorial. But, I read some stuff a while ago, that Google no longer use Deep App Linking. I guess they use App Indexing now. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/app#understand-your-site-links) is the info about App Indexing. Note that, maybe you can use Deep App Linking for now, but it can be deprecated. You can google it for further info.

You need to add deep app links to your webpage html files. Which when clicked from mobile browser, sends an intent to app. In Deep Indexing you don't need to do that I guess.

Sorry, I could've commented that, but my reputation is not enough.

Comment: Nothing's wrong with this. In my eyes it's qualified as an answer but because you didn't go into much details, I had to accept the other one. Though I've upvoted. Thanks,  it's an eye opener.